# How can I create a bytes object in python?

Tags: python-3.x, binary, byte

Alright I want to turn a binary string like `'1010110000000010'` into a `bytes` object in Python 3.3.2. Anyone know how I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `b'1010110000000010'`, use [`bytes`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes) or [`str.encode`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode):

```
>>> bytes('1010110000000010', encoding='ascii')
b'1010110000000010'
>>> '1010110000000010'.encode('ascii')
b'1010110000000010'
>>> '1010110000000010'.encode() # can omit encoding (default: utf-8)
b'1010110000000010'
```

If you want `b'\xac\x02'`, use [`bytes`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes) with converted integers (using [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) with base 2), or [`struct.pack`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack):

```
>>> bytes(int(b[i:i+8], 2) for i in range(0, len(b), 8))
b'\xac\x02'

>>> import struct
>>> b = '1010110000000010'
>>> b''.join(struct.pack('B', int(b[i:i+8], 2)) for i in range(0, len(b), 8))
b'\xac\x02'
```